# Rails gem for screen capturing

Tags: ruby, rubygems, screen-capture

Is there a gem or program for rails that is similar to screenflow or camtasia?  I'm making an application for people to have webinars, record their talks, and live chat during the webinar.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Screen capture is client OS dependent.  Rails is running on your web server.  There is no way a gem can do that for you.  You should use client side plugin technologies such as flash, java, etc to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a gem that uses ffmpeg to record your screen. I know it's probably late for OP, but leaving a link here in case anyone else has a use case for it - https://github.com/kapoorlakshya/ffmpeg-screenrecorder

Comment: Can it be used at the client side?

Comment: @Riteshkatare What do you mean by client side? It should work on any system (Windows, macOS, or Linux) with ffmpeg available. Please go through the README and let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Kapoorlakshya Rails app runs in a browser on client side & our ffmpeg will be installed on server, does it works on other machines from browser? If yes then Is it any dependency required to run recorder on that client's machine?

Comment: @Riteshkatare I don't think that's possible. ffmpeg has to be on the machine where the recording will happen i.e. on the user's computer.

I will be adding the streaming feature to the screen-recorder gem in the future, but still it will require the user to have the gem installed or at least have ffmpeg installed to broadcast their screen.